# Session Variables Not Working

Tags: session, session-variables

I am having a problem with my application. I am creating two session variables on a button click event, and then re-directing to another page and executing a method that selects data from a database (using the two session variables as parameters), and then displaying the results in a grid.

All works fine until I have two users (or more), who access the application, set their own session values, execute the data retrieval method, and of course they expect to see their own data.

What ends up occurring, is that both users see the same data, not their own specific data. Essentially, User A sees his data fine, but User B ends up seeing User A's data - not his own.

Note: this only occurs when they attempt to access their specific data 20 seconds apart

Here is my code sample:

```
//The user control that sets the session variables and redirects               
Session.Clear();
Session.["ID"] = TxtPatientIDCode.Text.ToString());
Session["DOB"] = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtDateOfBirth.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
Response.Redirect("mypage");

// the user control that gets the session variable values and executes //the data method                   
if (Session["ID"].ToString() != null)
{
    SelectData();
}
```

*Ammended*

This is what occurs on the SelectData() method:

```
private void SelectData()
{
    DataSet ds = Data.GetData(Session["ID"].ToString(),Session["DOB"].ToString());
    gv.DataSource = ds;
    gv.DataBind();
}
```

Also I did log this to a database table and it is inserting just fine, as it shows who and what times the data is accessed, as well as the session values that are being used.

Thanks again for the help
technooblet

Comment: Show what happens in SelectData().

Comment: Also... try logging what is in Session["ID"] and see if it is what you expect to be there.

Comment: Eric - I added additional code. Also I have sessionstate section on my web.config to perform a timeout of 15 minutes and cookieless="false"

Comment: What happens when you log what Session["ID"] is just before you use it?

Comment: Nothing, the Session["ID"] is simply inserted into the log table and the Session still remains to fetch the data. The Session is then cleared after the data is returned to the gridview.

Comment: I mean write Session["ID"] to a text file or something (you could use NLog... or just write to a file manually).  I suspect that the Session["ID"] is not being set to what you think.

Comment: It is indeed putputting correctly - both sessionids are inserting and writing to a database table. each session variable is inserting just fine for each individual session. unfortuantely, with this project we do not write to any text files or logs.